# GraphZoomscrollPane or Scrollbar on Layout; My dynamisch Graph endet wide out of Screen

Tags: scrollbar, jung, jung2

Can anybody tell me how can in build a scrollbar on my Layout. Some vertices from my Graph are endet away from Screen. I cant be able see them or scroll them . If i do zoom (out) then the vertices will be  very small, so that i cant see any edges or other vertices clearly.

thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GraphZoomScrollPaneDemo (in the distribution) demonstrates how to use GraphZoomScollPane correctly.  Have you looked at it?

Comment: thanks for replying.. I have tried ..:) 
Anothe question: i am using KKLayout 4 my Graph... the random Location from Vertices from my Graph is some time weis away From Screen. How can i fix an Area (width,  height), so that the KKlayout will use that area for Locating or placing all Nodes .